# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't debug and deploy on windows physical device

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, mobile-application

I'm developing an Xamarin forms(portable) app in Visual Studio 2015.In emulator application runs and results perfectly..
       My system config is much more then the required. I have connected my Windows phone to the computer and also it recognizes the device. 
       But when I debug the app in Visual Studio with device, its just processing for longer and doesn't results anything rather shows
**Microsoft VS is busy**
 and just visual studio hangs

**

> Currently i upgrade Windows SDK 10.0.26624 after that i faced this
>   issue

**

Comment: Did you set the Project in the Project Configuration to ARM and to Deploy?
Also in the Debug Settings of the Project to Device? And finally did you activate Debug Mode on your Phone?

Comment: yes even i get same failure ,In output window 'Deploy started: Project: xxx.WinPhone81, Configuration: Debug ARM'  just processing here not move further

Comment: Also Configure IP over USB too  .but in eumulator it runs ..